# Slide DIV from left

Tags: jquery, html, slide

I am trying to work with a simple div(leftContainer) and would like to make it slide from left to its total width on page load and not with a button click.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="leftContainer ">
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="mainbody">
    <p>Body</p>
</div>
```

​
**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YCVhH/7/)**

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @lbstr-sorry I just updated.Anyways I need to animate the total div(leftContainer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("div.leftContainer")
    .css("margin-left",-$(this).width())
    .animate({
        marginLeft:0
    }, 700);
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/duGkA/)

Comment: @kei-This is what I'm expecting.

Answer (score 3):

You can animate the width using jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/YCVhH/9/

```
$('.leftContainer').animate({ width: '100%'});​
```

Comment: @mrtsherman-First thanks for your reply.I need to animate from margin:0px to margin:308px ie the div width.

Comment: @coder - you mean like this? Margin-left = div width? Or do you need to slide it so that the right edge is up against the screen? http://jsfiddle.net/YCVhH/18/

Comment: @coder - here is one where it slides to other side of screen. Between these three hopefully I hit the mark! http://jsfiddle.net/YCVhH/21/

Comment: @mrtsherman-Thanks for the demo.Kei provided me the actual demo I need.

Answer (score 1):

made a simple example, dont know what you are trying to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/YCVhH/12/

use animate to do whatever you want [animate();](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

`$(".leftContainer").animate({
    left: "50%"
});`

Comment: @Ricardo-First thanks for your reply.I need to animate the div not from it's orginal posiion but from the margin:0px to it its total width

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("div.leftContainer").animate({width:100%}, "slow");
    });
</script>
```

If you're looking for a fixed width instead of 100%, change that as well. Good luck! If it doesn't work, please be more clear on what you want done, and I'll try to assist you.